# How to change "site_name" in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, configuration, drupal-6

This is probably a really obvious question, but it's driving me nuts.

We have a drupal installation and we need to change the site_name and site_slogan variables. It sounds like it should be easy, but I just can't find an option anywhere in the admin panels to do it. The only place I can find is in the initial installation script

I know I can write some code to call variable_set('site_name',...) to do it, but that seems like a last-ditch solution; I'd rather do it the correct way.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The form to change it is at site information: `admin/settings/site-information`.

Comment: Thank you -- I see it now. :-) No idea how I was missing it for so long.

Comment: @EricSchaefer no omg here, i'm overlooked a little bit. I thought admin/settings/site-information is a txt file somewhere, what more somehow i've combined this with Volker's answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it directly in the Database there is a table called variable. You can change it in there. In Drupal 6 this value is of type longtext, but in Drupal 7 this value is of type blob. It is serialized so you cannot simply write to it with an update query, and expect it to work.

I have some code here that shows how to write to it.
http://www.siteconsortium.com/h/p1.php?id=drpl001

Also, if you are using Drupal 7 it shows how to go to the configuration settings and modify the site_name and site_mail variables.

Don't forget to clear the caches if you have caching setup.

Answer (score -2):

It seems that you have to edit sites/default/settings.php:

http://mblog.lib.umich.edu/DataDiscussions/archives/2009/10/change_the_site.html

It answers the slogan thingy also.

Since I'm not using drupal anymore, you have to verify it by yourself :-)

Greetings